# Jelly bean voice search not talking back

Tags: voice-command, 4.1-jelly-bean, voice-recognition

I've recently upgraded my phone to Android 4.1.1 and I've tried the new voice search.
It mostly answers my questions correctly, but i didn't get it to talk back.

I checked the following setting: Settings->Voice->Speech Output. It's set to Always.

Does anybody else have this issue? Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Voice Search/Google Now only speaks back to me on particular searches. What spoken search term(s) are you expecting a verbal response to?

Comment: Ask it "Who is the President of the United States?".  It seems to talk back to everyone for that one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you made sure that your "Music volume" is actually turned up? Only then you'll be able to hear the talk-back.

To make sure it is, go to the stock music app, hit the "Volume up" key on your phone a few times, then go back to Google Voice Search and try again.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that was the problem. I feel pretty silly for not checking the volume, but to be honest i didn't even think about it. I expected that after a fresh install it will be at a high enough level to hear the voice.

Comment: This isn't working for me on Kit Kat. I've checked to make sure that the language is set to English(US) and all the other common advice, but still no luck. Weirdly, it _was_ working this morning, so something must have changed, but I have no idea what.